# Error when deploying project to scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I am facing a problem when deploying a project to my scratch org. I have a custom object named Project Information. This object is accessible to admins and user and the permission is set using permission sets. When i try to execute sfdx:force:push -u ProjectMgmtScratch, i am receiving an error like this.

> force-app\main\default\layouts\Project_Information__c-Project
>   Information Layout.layout-meta.xml  Invalid field:TASK.SUBJECT in
>   related list:RelatedActivityList.

I haven't touched the Task object but still facing this error. Has anyone had issue like this?

Comment: Are there any differences between your settings on activities on your scratch org and any org you developed this code on?

Comment: I edited my object and unchecked Allow Sharing, Allow Streaming and some other checkboxes. In the sharing settings, I changed public Read/Write to Public Read only. I had pushed admin and other custom profiles before. I deleted those profiles from remote (origin/master) and that's all the change I made.
I even created a new scratch org and tried pushing the project but unfortunately received Invalid field:TASK.SUBJECT in related list:RelatedActivityList error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove my duplicate rule and matching rule from my project. This might be a bug in salesforce(not sure).

I tried deactivating the rules but unfortunately could not deploy it. So, try deleting the matchingrule and duplicaterule folders.

Edit: 
don't forget to delete the references of these rules from **sourcePathInfos.json** and **metadataTypeInfos.json**. These files contain matching and duplicate rule paths.